# Style tag does not work in gmail even though docs say otherwise

Tags: html, gmail

I try to create responsive design for my emails, some basics like setting width of table to 100% on mobile or change color of text, it works in desktop client app like Thunderbird, but it fails to work on both android and desktop version of Gmail. I tried to find answers on the internet, but I can't find any recent info about this.

I follow guidelines from gmail official site, so I guess it should work. https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .colored {
        color: blue;
      }
      #body {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
        .colored {
          color:red;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='body'>
      <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
      <p class='colored'>
        This text is blue if the window width is
        below 500px and red otherwise.
      </p>
      <p>Jerry</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It should have blue color on mobile version and red on desktop app. Well, it has none on them on both.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It shows up red when I test it.

Answer (score -1):

change min to max!

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .colored {
        color: blue;
      }
      #body {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
        .colored {
          color:red;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='body'>
      <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
      <p class='colored'>
        This text is blue if the window width is
        below 500px and red otherwise.
      </p>
      <p>Jerry</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```